# Battery drains even while laptop lid closed (Ubuntu 19.04 & Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th gen)

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, thinkpad, 19.04

Any other thinkpad x1 carbon users on ubuntu 19.04 notice that the battery still drains even while the laptop lid is closed & suspended?

I updated from 18.10 to 19.04 about two weeks ago, and ever since, I've come home from the work and found my laptop burning up in my backpack with the battery drained 50% or more after half a day closed & (I assume) suspended.

I had this problem for a while with 18.10, but it went away after a thnkpad BIOS update included the linux sleep state.

Thanks in advance

Screenshot of my battery discharge from the past 6 hours (my laptop was closed and "suspended" for 5.5 of those hours):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnZyT.jpg

Comment: Are you *certain* that the laptop was in fact suspended? Because the power statistics claims to have data points from essentially equally spaced intervals through this time. Is it a possibility that it was still powered fully on, with the screen off?

Comment: Is there a way to check a log of suspensions/resumes to verify?

Comment: I saw the same on 19.04, if you check power settings, there is no sleep on lid close

Comment: check your logs with `dmesg` to see if it went into suspend.
`dmesg | grep sleep`